# Specific digit count in an integer in C

Tags: c, arrays

For example: if user input is 11234517 and wants to see the number of 1's in this input, output will be "number of 1's is 3. i hope you understand what i mean.

i am only able to count number of digits in an integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n, count = 0;

    printf("Enter an integer number:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while (n != 0)
    {
        n/=10;
        count++;
    }
    printf("Digits in your number: %d",count);
    return 0;
}
```

maybe arrays are the solution. Any help would be appreciated. thank you!

Comment: hint: use the `%` operator within the `while`'s loop body in order to find out specific digit.

Comment: Why are you ignoring the return value of `scanf()`?

Comment: Hint: how do you print out each digit from an `int` value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you've already found that you can convert `1234` to `123` (that is, remove the least significant digit) by using `number / 10`.

If we wanted to acquire the least significant digit, we could use `number % 10`. For `1234`, that would have the value of `4`.

Understanding this, we can then modify your code to take this into account:

```
int main() {
    int n, count = 0;

    printf("Enter an integer number:");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    while (n != 0) {
        if (n % 10 == 1)
            count++;
        n /= 10;
    }

    printf("Number of 1s in your number: %d", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need array. Try something like this:

```
int countDigits(int number, int digitToCount)
{
  // Store how many times given number occured
  int counter = 0;

  while(number != 0)
  {
   int tempDigit = number % 10;
   if(tempDigit == digitToCount)
     counter++;
   number = number/10;
  }

 return counter;
}
```

Comment: Minor: `countDigits(0, 0)` returns `0`.  I would expect `1`.  Using a `do {} while ()` rather than `while () {}` would remedy that.

Comment: @chux: true, or just put check if both are zero and return 1:). I don't like `do..while`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [convert your int to a string](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm) like this :

```
char str[100];
sprintf(str, "%d", n);
```

Then, you can just iterate on `str` in order to find the occurrences of your digit.