# Specific digit count from inputted integer in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops

This is a code where a specific digit is counted from an inputted integer number. I've already done this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

  int number, digitToCount;
  scanf("%d %d", &number, &digitToCount);

  int counter = 0;

  while (number != 0) {
    int tempDigit = number % 10;
    if (tempDigit == digitToCount)
      counter++;
    number = number / 10;
  }

  printf("%d", counter);

  return counter;
}
```

But is there any way to do that like this way? Is this method correct? Where is the error in this code below?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
  int c = 0, n, t = 0, d;

  printf("Enter an integer number:");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  printf("desired digit:");
  scanf("%d", &d);

  char str[50], str2[0];
  sprintf(str, "%d", n);
  sprintf(str2, "%d", d);

  for (t = 0; t <= 50; t++) {
    if (str2[0] == str[t]) {

      c = c + 1;
    }

  }

  printf("%d", c);

  return c;
}
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `t <= 50` and `char str2[0]` are wrong.

Comment: whats right then? everything else is correct then?

Comment: array out of bounds error for t = 50 because the array is numbered 0 to 49, and also for str2[0] making a 0 sized array

Comment: e.g. `t <= 50` --> `str[t] != '\0'`, `char str[50], str2[16];`

Comment: First method fails for `number == 0, digitToCount ==0`.  Change `while (number != 0) { ...  }` --> `do { ...  } while (number != 0)`.

Comment: Kind of presumptuous to say "I've already done this" when it's just copied and slightly altered from the answer to your earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28563327/specific-digit-count-in-an-integer-in-c ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you could make an approach along the latter lines work, it is probably less efficient than the former approach.  You'll not notice that for a problem this size, but it is well to be aware that formatting (i.e. converting between text and internal data types) is comparatively expensive.

What's worse, in your second approach you are trying to convert from text to a number and then back to text.  Why?  It's not *completely* meaningless, as it will slightly change your program's behavior on some cases of non-numeric input (it will fail differently), but if you want the data as a char array then read it that way in the first place:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
  char str[50], d;
  int c = 0, t;

  printf("Enter an integer number:");
  scanf("%49s", str);

  printf("desired digit:");
  scanf("%c", &d);

  for (t = 0; str[t] != '\0'; t++) {
    if (str[t] == d) {
      c = c + 1;
    }
  }

  printf("%d", c);

  return 0;
}
```

There are still problems with that, mostly around validating your inputs, but it should work for valid inputs, as well as having possibly-useful behavior for some arguably invalid ones.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you keep the source number as string. Something like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    char num[256];
    char search;
    int i, count;
    scanf("%s[0-9] %c", num, search);

    if (search < '0' || search > '9') {
        printf("invalid search");
        return -1
        }
    for(i=0, count=0; num[i]; i++) {
        if (num[i] == search)
            count++;
        }
    print("matches %d\n", count);
    return 0;
    }
```